# Add custom text in first li of drop down

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
 if (this.is_multiple) {
            this.container.html('<ul class="chosen-choices"><li class="search-field"><input type="text" value="' + this.default_text + '" class="default" autocomplete="off" placeholder="choose your&nbsp;' + this.default_text + '" style="width:25px;" /></li></ul><div class="chosen-drop"><ul class="chosen-results"><li class="choose"></li></ul></div>');
        } else {
            this.container.html('<a class="chosen-single chosen-default" tabindex="-1"><span>' + this.default_text + '</span><div><b></b></div></a><div class="chosen-drop"><div class="chosen-search"><input type="text" autocomplete="off" /></div><ul class="chosen-results"></ul></div>');
        }
        this.form_field_jq.hide().after(this.container);
        this.dropdown = this.container.find('div.chosen-drop').first();
        this.search_field = this.container.find('input').first();



        this.search_results = this.container.find('ul.chosen-results').first();

        this.search_field_scale();
        this.search_no_results = this.container.find('li.no-results').first();
        if (this.is_multiple) {
            this.search_choices = this.container.find('ul.chosen-choices').first();
            this.search_container = this.container.find('li.search-field').first();
        } else {
            this.search_container = this.container.find('div.chosen-search').first();
            this.selected_item = this.container.find('.chosen-single').first();
        }
```

I want to add custom text in first li of dropdown. How I add this Please give me suggestion.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `$('#dropdownElement li:first').append('foo bar');`

Comment: Thanks for reply. i am beginner  can u please tell me where to put this code.

Comment: What do you mean by "custom text"? What should the result be?

Comment: Custom text means "I want add to write 'Choose your emotion'  in first li field and it be disabled"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the jquery like this.

```
$(function(){
var content='Choose your emotion';
$("<li disabled>"+content+"</li>").prependTo("ul.chosen-results");
});
```

Comment: did you try this?

Comment: var content='Choose your emotion';
             $("<li>"+content+"</li>").prependTo("ul.chosen-results");     I am using this but not working

Comment: i have to add li on choosen-results class and the li value is coming dynamically.

Comment: what is your `ul` class name `chosen-results` or `chosen-choices`?

Comment: chosen-results is class name

Comment: yeah this class name

Comment: did you check in console?whether it append or not?

Comment: var content='Choose your';
            $("<li disabled>"+content+"</li>").prependTo("ul.chosen-results");     nothing show but when i add with other class it works . Why this not working for this particular class

Comment: your class has loaded to the DOM?is it in the web page?

Comment: ya that is the problem..If dom doesn't have the class then jquery and javascript wont trigger..Which means you are trying to append the list to undefined class